# JIRA attachment with REST API

Tags: python, json, rest, jira, jira-rest-api

I want to upload attachment while creating JIRA ticket, I tried the format below but its not working with syntax error given for the file. Do you have any idea how to create this in a json file ?

```
    data = {
        "fields": {
            "project": {
                "key": project
            },
            "attachments" : [
                "file": "C:\data.txt"
                ],
            "summary": task_summary,
            "issuetype": {
                "name": "Task"
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only set issue fields during creation: https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#d2e2786

You can add attachments to already existing issues by posting the content itself: https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#d2e2035

Sou you have to do it in two steps.

Answer (score 0):

It works now, i was not using rest/api/2/issue/DEV-290/attachments